# Why no symbols defined for ascii values from 127 to 159

Tags: html, character-encoding, ascii, ascii-art

I was looking for `&times;` in [an ASCII chart](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) and noticed that from 127 to 159 there are no symbols defined in the chart (`not defined in HTML 4 standard`), although codes thereafter do have symbols in the chart.

Is there a specific technical reason for not having symbols in this number range?

Comment: Because this HTML encoding follows [Latin1 Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). Latin1 does not have characters in that range. Therefore, HTML does not have characters in that range. No further "technical" reason is required.

Comment: Sometimes I really dont understand voting system here :( I already read the part "Don't ask about..." and thought it is ok with the rules but still down votes :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no Ascii values greater than 127 (decimal), and Ascii value 127 stands for an invisible control character. Ascii defines a character code that assigns meanings to code numbers from 0 and 127, and that’s it. What people commonly call “8-bit Ascii” is nothing more that *some* 8-bit character code that has the same assignments for code numbers from 0 to 127 as Ascii.

The “ASCII chart” page you link to has several errors, including incorrect use of the term “ASCII”. It should not be used as a reference.

Comment: @JukkaKKorpela You are saying `no Ascii values greater than 127` but after 160 there are acii values in the chart..if its not then what are they as some of them we commonly use like `&copy;` and `&times;`

Comment: `&copy;` and `&times;` are entity references (HTML term before HTML5) or named character references (HTML5 term), and they denote the Unicode characters “©” and “×”. This has nothing to do with Ascii.

Answer (score 4):

While it's not clear if this was the original intention of the designers of ASCII, but limiting ASCII to values 127 or less (decimal) has allowed the creation of newer character encodings like UTF-8 and Unicode, that support over a Million characters, while also being BACKWARDS COMPATIBLE with ASCII.

These newer encoding schemes do this by being variable-width: if the first bit in a Byte is '0' the Byte is treated as an ASCII character. If the first Byte is a '1' it's treated as part of a multi-Byte character.
More info on UTF-8 is available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Software that is UTF-8 compliant can therefore process text originally encoded in ASCII. Again, this backwards compatibility applies to encoding designed to be backwards compatible with ASCII. There are certainly other encoding schemes which are **not** backwards compatible.

More characters is very important because even a 8 bits (256 characters) or a full Byte wouldn't be enough to represent all the characters in all the languages people are interested in, especially because languages like Chinese and Japanese have thousands of characters. Even 2 Bytes doesn't cover languages like Chinese and Japanese.

Backwards compatible encodings allow both legacy software, and new software that is UTF-8 compliant to process the same text data, as they both new and legacy software treat ASCII characters the same, and won't mix up ASCII characters with other characters and vice-versa.

Another advantage of multi-Byte encoding schemes, vs an approach that allocates a fixed amount of say 3 or 4 Bytes per character (which you need to support Japanese and Chinese, as 2 Bytes isn't enough), is that with fixed with encodings, you'll dramatically increase the storage requirements for simple text (meaning text which can ASCII or 1 Byte per character), as now every character is 3 or 4 Bytes, instead of 1.

A fixed width encoding scheme (e.g. 3 or 4 Bytes per character) also wouldn't be backwards compatible with ASCII.

So, don't criticize ASCII for not making use of all 8 bits bit, or not supporting up to 256 characters, but praise it for being extensible, so that we have the genie emoji ‍♂️. Yes, many/most emoji are official UTF-8 and Unicode characters — but devices and fonts need to create graphics for them, which lags the actual creation of the emoji as an official character, so new emojis like Llamas are not available on Mac (yet), but are available on iOS.

Answer (score 2):

This numerical HTML encoding follows [Latin1 Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), and Latin1 does not have characters in that range. Therefore, HTML does not have characters in that range. No further "technical" reason is required.

The reason these codes do not define visible characters in *Latin1* is more complicated. The space is reserved for [C1 control codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) (`0x80` to `0x9F`), which are (very) old terminal formatting commands. They are similar in purpose to [C0 control codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) (`0x00` to `0x1F`), which also used to define functions, such as "Vertical Tab", "Ack", and "Bell", which have been deprecated and gone out of use, with the exception of Tab, Carriage Return, and Line Feed (and possibly Backspace).

Comment: I was thinking of mentioning raw Tab, CR, and LF characters do not "mean" anything in HTML (they are, per specs, regarded "a single space"). Can we consider the contents of `<pre>` to be "not part of HTML"?

Comment: HTML has for a long time had Unicode as its character code, not Latin1. Code numbers from 127 to 159 are assigned to control characters in Unicode, which means that they correspond to characters–but they control characters with undefined meaning (as far as Unicode is concerned), and they are prohibited (invalid) in HTML.