# json_encode() character 127 ASCII

Tags: php, json

Consider the following code:

```
$str = '';
for ($i=0x0; $i<=0x7f; $i++) {
   $str .= chr($i);
}

echo json_encode($str);
```

The result is:

```
"\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005\u0006\u0007\b\t\n\u000b\f\r\u000e\u000f\u0010\u0011\u0012\u0013\u0014\u0015\u0016\u0017\u0018\u0019\u001a\u001b\u001c\u001d\u001e\u001f !\"#$%&'()*+,-.\/0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"
```

There are all **but one** ASCII characters (the last one): **127 (0x7f)**.

Is there a way to show that character? (for instance: "\u007f")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete (DEL) is a control character in the ASCII character set with the coding 0x7f or 127 decimal. This character is saved as ASCII in the JSON string. This character can be made visible by outputting the JSON string in hexadecimal format.

```
$jsonStr = json_encode(chr(0x7f));
echo bin2hex($jsonStr);  //227f22
```

22 is the encoding for a double quotation mark ("). echo is not suitable for checking what is in a string. There are always misunderstandings. Control characters (including DEL) are only displayed as spaces in the browser. If you look closely at the result of your code example, you will see the space at the end.

Comment: I think json_encode() should encode this character as \u007f, just like it does the other control characters (ex: backspace \b). But for some reason it has been left that way.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think this is what you are searching for:

U+007F

Also see this answer: [Why no symbols defined for ascii values from 127 to 159](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606965/why-no-symbols-defined-for-ascii-values-from-127-to-159)